# hmvc codeigniter uri routing

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I have and CI hmvc structure as below:

- application

  - config

    - config.php
    - ***routes.php***
  - ...
  - modules

    - login
    - personal

      - config

        - config.php
        - ***routes.php***
      - controllers
      - libraries
      - models
      - views

HMVC works fine. So, here's my problem: Inside **/modules/personal/config/routes.php** i have this:

*$route['personal/empleados/actualizar.legajo'] = 'personal/empleados/actualizar_legajo/';
$route['personal/empleados/nuevo-cargo'] = 'personal/empleados/nuevo_cargo/';*

But it doen't work. The file is loaded but routing doesn't work.

If i cut and copy these two lines and paste them inside: **/application/config/routes.php**, works.

Can anybody tell me why ? Because i have several modules and i would like to do this inside each **modules/module-name/config/config.php**

Thanx, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the default controller in each module ?
You may also need to add the folder path.

#### modules/personal/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'personal';

// OR //

$route['default_controller'] = 'personal/personal';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your answer. 
I set my default controller as you tell but it fails anyway.
On the other hand i found a solution (?) as follow on **modules/module-name/config/routes.php**

***$route['personal/empleados/nuevo.cargo'] = 'empleados/nuevo_cargo/';***

and... IT WORKS. I don't know why. But it works.